# How to install PHP API for sphinx

Tags: php, ubuntu, sphinx

I've installed the sphinx tool on my Ubuntu machine using `sphinxsearch`. I cannot find any Ubuntu package to support php-sphinx.

Where should I get PHP API for sphinx from?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SphinxSearch#Step_8.1_-_Extension_Preparation_-_Sphinx_PHP_API states to download the tarball from the webpage http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/release/ to get the "sphinxapi.php file"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sphinx API is PHP file with functions. You can download it from sphinx site.

But now most recommended use SphixQL - this is language similar to SQL and you can use it with php-mysql extension.

Comment: yep, svn export http://sphinxsearch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ sphinxsearch

Answer (score 2):

The PHP API is only a PHP file you have to include.

Answer (score 0):

Googling "Sphinx php installation" gave the following result:

http://php.net/manual/en/sphinx.installation.php

Comment: I try to avoid pecl/pear and pear and prefer composable/githable libs instead. Pecl/pear are near dead communities and projects

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz Then if the first result in a Google search doesn't work, move to the next ones. http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html clearly states that PHP libs are included in the project. You need to research before you ask a question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @james Install sphinx #wtf